# PHP script in eclipse needs extensions in php.ini

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt

I have a PHP script with PDO.

On the command line it runs OK.

But to run it in eclipse I have to edit php.ini. I have to add

```
extension=pdo.so
```

Can someone explain me this?

Thanks,

Eric J.

Comment: I think you are using two php.ini  , one for command line and other for website (eclipse).  use the phpinfo() in command line and eclipse  and check this.

Comment: Where can I see it in phpinfo?

Comment: Search for `Loaded Configuration File`  and  `additional .ini files parsed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

The include_path option in the php.ini specified in the Eclipse preferences is ignored when "Run > as PHP script".

Reproducible: Always

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Launch a script with phpinfo() in command line
2. In eclipse, configure the php executable, with its php.ini
3. In eclipse, run the php "as PHP script", and see that the include_path is not the same as the one in the command line

Comment: NullPointer, Thanks, I see what you mean. With an eclipse configuration, there is no include_path. What I see is that eclipse copies php.ini in a /tmp directory , and and .ini files in php.d directory on my fedora machine are missed. Can one fix that in eclipse?